# How to pass value to python in flask api from a input field

Tags: python, html, flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>
        <h1>We Would Like to know your name </h1>
        <h2>192.168.29.109</h2>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="10"><br><br>
        <button onclick="https://">GO FURTHER</button>
    <a href="/user/<username>">Submit</a><br /> 
        <a href="/rango/about">About</a><br />
        <img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image">
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

from here python flask file I have only 1 file

```
#IMPORTING
from flask import Flask , render_template
from flask_script import Manager
from wtforms import StringField
import os


#Launching Server
app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)


#Settings..!
PEOPLE_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'people_photo')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = PEOPLE_FOLDER




#Defining URL's And Rendering!
@app.route('/index')
def index():
   full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'lkj.jpg')
   return render_template("index.html", user_image = full_filename)


@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
 return '<h1>Hey %s, Welcome to Flask</h1>' % name




#Deployment
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
    #app.run(debug=True)
```

Okay so I wanted to pass the value from input field to python flask file where I have defined @app.route(/user/)
in the input field I asked someone's name he put the name and I wanted to take that name and put it in the user/ and display his name I can manually do that  by writing the url myself like '192.168.29.10:5000/user/laxman' it would display 'Hey Laxman...etc' but I wanted that its done through the input field from that the parameters are passed and flask take that and display 'Hey Name...etc' so Can anyone help I only have two files and I have showed them already abobe  SO anyone's help will be appreciated pls Thankyou
:)
If you want to ask anything ask I am gonna tell you! thankyou!

Comment: use form to submit value

Comment: CAN YOU ELAOBRATE MORE!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your input into a form and submit it to the /user view.

```
<form action="/user"> 
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="10"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then in your view function

```
@app.route('/user')
def user():
   who = request.args.get('username')
   # Do something with who
   return render_template("user.html", name=who)
```

Comment: How can I redirect it to another url with the username sir can I know? :)

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean. This will redirect to www.example.com/user?username=<who>